# I am using JqGrid (1.8.22) in JSP page and datatype XML , but pager is not working here

Tags: jqgrid

Without data pagination buttons are clickable [**IMAGE** 1](https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-XeHuKfr-3J0/UkkK-WwW8OI/AAAAAAAAAE8/pbzPiQwgpy4/w511-h234-no/withoutdata.png)
Here pagination buttons are not clickable     [**IMAGE** 2](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-s7uJYwsQTOE/UkkKt4vc8gI/AAAAAAAAAEU/E3x0mEhGx-M/w507-h234-no/withdata.png)

> Here pager is not working if data is dynamic. Please let me know what
>   change i have to do, it works only if we use static data.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery().ready(function() {
jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
url : './ShowDummyData.do?',
datatype : 'XML',
mtype : 'GET',
loadonce : false,
colNames:['Inv No','Notes','DTL'],
colModel:[
{name:'invid',index:'invid', width:150},
{name:'note',index:'note', width:150, sortable:false},
{name:'dtl',index:'dtl', width:150, sortable:false}         
],                          
pager : jQuery('#pager'),
rowNum : 1,
rowList : [ 1, 2, 3 ],
rownumbers: true,
viewrecords : true,
gridview: true,
caption : 'My first grid'
}).navGrid('#pager',{edit:false,add:false,del:false});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="list" class="scroll"></table>
<div id="pager" class="scroll" style="text-align: center;"></div>
</body>
```

> Here is the code for servlet

```
sb.append("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>");
response.setContentType("text/xml;charset=utf-8");
sb.append("<rows>");
sb.append("<row id='3'>");
sb.append("<cell>1</cell>");
sb.append("<cell>777</cell>");
sb.append("<cell> We will do 3</cell>");
sb.append("</row>");
 sb.append("<row id='4'>");
sb.append("<cell>1</cell>");
sb.append("<cell>777</cell>");
sb.append("<cell> We will do 3</cell>");
sb.append("</row>");
sb.append("</rows>");
```

> returns data in xml format

Comment: The current version of jqGrid is 4.5.2. Version 1.8.22 is probably the version of jQuery UI which you use. How you imagine that somebody helps you if you don't include the code which you use? Do you implemented **server side paging** of data? If you want load all data at once you can use `loadonce: true` option of jqGrid. In any way more details are required to understand what you want to implement and what wrong you do.

Comment: Yes I agree, actually  i am new to stack overflow and was trying to add code , it was showing some format error,

Comment: Here is the code                              jQuery().ready(function() {jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
url : './ShowDummyData',
datatype : "xml",
colNames : [ 'Inv No', 'Date', Amount','Tax', 'Total', 'Notes' ],
rowNum : 10,
rowList : [ 10, 20, 30 ],
pager : jQuery('#pager'),
sortname : 'id',
viewrecords : true,
sortorder : "desc",
}).navGrid('#pager', {
edit : false,});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <table id="list" class="scroll"></table>
 <div id="pager" class="scroll" style="text-align: center;"></div>
</body>

Comment: You should click on "edit" link below the text of your question to modify the text and to append it to additional information. [Here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/147495) for example you can read how to format the text with JavaScript or HTML code. Comment should be used for writing short information only. For example you can write short comment to me to inform about changing of the text of your question. I asked you befor which version of jqGrid you use and whether the server (`'./ShowDummyData'`) returns *the requested page* of data (up to 10 rows) only or if it returns *all data*.

Comment: Thanks Oleg, i posted my code properly which includes the jsp code ans servlet code (which returns xml data to jsp),

Answer (score 0):

You use `loadonce: false` (by the way it's default value). So **your server code** (the servlet) is responsible to the paging. For example, you use `rowNum: 1`. It means that you want to display 1 row per page. Initial page during creating of grid is 1. So jqGrid send the following additional parameters to the server:

```
page=1
rows=1 (get from rowNum: 1)
```

The URL `./ShowDummyData.do` will be appended with `./ShowDummyData.do?page=1&rows=1` and some other additional parameters (`sidx`, `sord`, `_search`, `nd`). Your server code should read the parameters of requests and it should return **the requested page** of data: the first page with one row. So the server should first sort the data corresponds `sidx` and `sord` parameters, it should divide the result in pages and it should return *only one page*.

If you want that client code (jqGrid itself) make paging the servlet should return *all data* like you do currently and you should use `loadonce: true` option.

Comment: Thanks, but for my page pagination button are not clickable, i checked in IE and Crome both

Comment: @Tina: You wrote "pager is not working". You should describe more clear what you mean. Do you included jQuery UI CSS on your page? Take a look in [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:first_grid#html_file) and compare the `<head>` part of your page with the example from the documentation.

Comment: @ Oleg, i wanted to add screen shot , but as i don't have 10 reputation,its not allowing me. They problem is if i dnt have data in my page, the pagination buttons are clickable, but suppose i have 2 records and i m showing 1 record per page then pagination button is not clickable for me, so i cant see the second record.

Comment: i posted the link of the screen shots above.